# Add Permanent Tagged Value

Tags: tags, uml, enterprise-architect

I would like to add a permanent tagged value to each `requirement` element in the model.

I know that for adding a tagged value to the drop-dwon list, I have to define the tagged value in **Settings | UML Types | Tagged Value Types tab**,
 but I would like to add the new tagged value to a particular element.

Can I perform it in `Enterprise Architect`? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the tagged value in the **Settings | UML Types | Tagged Value Types tab**,
adding to the 'detail' window the string:`AppliesTo=TypeName;`  , gives the result.